# set certain item in nav walker to active when on archive pages or singles

Tags: menus, navigation

I have created an event custom post type and a link in my menu to the archive page for that event (/events).

I'm using `wp_nav_menu()` to call the menu.

When I'm on /events the menu has the `current_menu_item` class and I've styled that to change colors.  This works perfectly.

I'd like to enhance this a bit though by setting that menu item to active whenever anyone is on a certain page as well.

I created a page to show my past events (/past-events). It's being driven by a file called `page-past-events.php`. The idea is that when a user is on `/past-events` the events link shows as active.  Since I don't have a menu item for that I want the `event` menu item to have the active class.  Ideally this item would be active when a user is on any of the single events as well (events/event-12).

my current code is

```
  wp_nav_menu(array(
       'theme_location' => 'headerMenu',
  ));
```

I found this code for my functions.php:

```
function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {
    if ( is_page('past-events') ) {
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

But it doesn't target my events menu item.

I can do it with script like this:

```
<?php if (is_page('past-events')) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var d = document.getElementById("menu-item-15");
        d.className += " current-menu-item";
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

But I was hoping for a "WordPress" way.

**EDIT**

`/events` a custom link in the wp menu that links to the events archive.

The slug for events is events

`/past-events` is a single page with its own template `page-past-events.php`

So if someone is on the past events page the menu item for /events gets the active class and for all intents and purposes is highlighted as active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it properly, this would do what you wanted:

```php
function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {
    if (
        // 1. The menu item is for the "/events" page. Be sure to change the "123"
        //    (i.e. the "/events" page ID).
        ( 'page' === $item->object && 123 == $item->object_id ) &&
        // 2. The current page is "Past Events" or that it's a "Event" single page.
        //    If "event" isn't the correct post type, change it.
        ( is_page( 'past-events' ) || is_singular( 'event' ) )
    ) {
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

### UPDATE

So if the `/events` menu item is a **custom link**:

```php
function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {
    if (
        ( 'custom' === $item->type && 'events' === $item->post_name ) &&
        ( is_page( 'past-events' ) || is_singular( 'event' ) )
    ) {
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

If that does not work, then try checking against the *menu item ID* (here it's `456`):

```php
function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {
    if (
        456 == $item->ID &&
        ( is_page( 'past-events' ) || is_singular( 'event' ) )
    ) {
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for helping!  This didn't seem to work though.  You're correct: /events is a custom link that links to the events archive.  I'll post a little more details in the question.

Comment: Have you tried using `( 'custom' === $item->type && 'events' == $item->post_name )` ? And I've updated the answer, but if it still doesn't work, then maybe you can try `wp_reset_query();`?

Comment: I'll try them both when I'm back at work.  thanks again.

Comment: I'm just wondering if the code worked for you, or perhaps you used another solution? :)

Comment: ack.  I'll check today!